External Displays not showing anything
I'm using a docking station (Lenovo) to connect 2 external displays (HP Z23i) to my laptop (Thinkpad E15 gen 2). The used cables are DisplayPort ones. The problem is the laptop can detect the monitors, I can see/change the properties of the external displays, but they show nothing, just blank screen. I've tried literally all the suggested ways in the internet, but none worked for me. Also, the same setup works fine for my phone - If I plug in the type C cable to my phone, the displays project the phone screen. Hence, I checked all the configs for possible missync, but looks like from refresh rate to screen ratio are the same for both the laptop and the external displays. Any suggestion please? How can I make it work?
